# Show selection of point in relation of a vector field?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, attribute-joins, streets, relation

I have two files,

1. vector "streets"
2. a series of point "civic numers" or "address"

I want to select a random street and have the field selection of the relative civic number on that street.
Those have a similar field, "Tomponyms", and i want to be able to open the attributes fileds of both layer and have them selected.

I saw that this is possible in arcmap, by simply right-clicking the both of the columns of the attributes fileds and make a Join oh these.

On qgis I tried use the Project > Proprieties > Relations but it don't work,
I also tried Layer > Join but it doesn't work either.

Comment: You want to click/select a street, and all points on that street should automatically be selected?

Comment: yes, and if possible, the other way around

Answer (score 0):

On the point layer, create a virtual field of data type boolean with this expression. All point on the selected street will be `true`, all others `false`:

```
is_selected( 
    'street',
    get_feature_by_id (
        'street', 
        overlay_nearest ('street', $id)[0]
    )
)
```